# Why CrossAxisAligment not Working in Flex,Row and Column?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Flutter Demo'
        ),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Hell World!'
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Why the text `Hell World` only centering horizontally and not vertically as I have also specified `CrossAxisAligment`.**

Is it because of this : [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19203)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Row` don't take all the vertical space available by default. It takes only the needed space (but it takes all the horizontal space).

Forcing the row to expend vertically should do the trick:

```
body: SizedBox.expand(
  child: Row(...),
),
```

Comment: Then what is the use of CrossAxisAligment as if it can't control things across cross axis?

Comment: `crossAxisAlignment` control the position of the elements, not the size of the row. We'd need a `crossAxisSize` instead, similarly to `mainAxisSize`. But this doesn't exists, because alignments such as `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` makes the row fill the vertical space.

Comment: That makes sense..we need something like `crossAxisSize`

Answer (score 1):

use center widget

```
Center(child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: <Widget>[Text('Hell World!')],))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to wrap the widget **Row** with another parent widget say **Container** or **SizedBox** or **SizedBox.expand** which can define its size and that can be used by the child widget **Row** to deduce the boundary size of its parent widget.

```
body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [Text(‘Hello World’)],
        ),
      ),
```

**Note:** If you use **SizedBox.expand()** which might have a parent widget that exceeds the screen size or have infinite length then it won't work. Say while using **SingleChildScrollView**, using **SizedBox.expand()** won't work for the above issue. In that case you need to use **SizedBox/Container** and define **width**/**height** manually for **Column/Row** respectively.