# How to give different elements different cross axis alignment in a Flutter Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The desired outcome is for there to be an icon in the top left corner of the container that stays in place (fixed top, no centering) while a multiline text field expands when the text becomes long, making the container expand. There's also an icon on the right of the container that would be vertically centered.

If it were possible to give different elements in a row different crossAxisAlignment (some start, some center for example) I would be able to solve this problem.

If there was a way to make row elements know and match the height of their tallest sibling, then I could also solve this problem.

I've considered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073674/why-crossaxisaligment-not-working-in-flex-row-and-column), but the Container that surrounds the Row has a min height and not a max height. When I use SizedBox.expand (as suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073674/why-crossaxisaligment-not-working-in-flex-row-and-column)), I get a `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height` error. I don't want to give the surrounding container a max height, or force anything to expand to a max height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted my solution into a VariableCrossAxisAlignmentRow / Column / Flex widget and am posting it.

Here's a screenshot of my example:

[image]

And here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Variable Cross Axis Alignment Flex',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _alignments = [
      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    ];
    final _flexValues = [1, 2, null, 1];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Variable Cross Axis Alignment Flex'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
              width: 400,
              height: 700,
              child: VariableCrossAxisAlignmentColumn(
                  flexValues: _flexValues,
                  alignments: _alignments,
                  minWidth: 400,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 280,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: Size.infinite.height,
                      child: Text(
                        'Flex: ${_flexValues[0]}, ${_alignments[0]}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 280,
                      height: Size.infinite.height,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text(
                        'Flex: ${_flexValues[1]}, ${_alignments[1]}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 280,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      height: 250,
                      child: Text(
                        'Flex: ${_flexValues[2]}, ${_alignments[2]}, height: 250',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 280,
                      height: Size.infinite.height,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Text(
                        'Flex: ${_flexValues[3]}, ${_alignments[3]}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]))),
    );
  }
}

class VariableCrossAxisAlignmentFlex extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int?> flexValues;
  final Axis direction;
  final List<CrossAxisAlignment> alignments;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final double crossAxisMinSize;
  const VariableCrossAxisAlignmentFlex(
      {required this.flexValues,
      required this.alignments,
      required this.children,
      required this.direction,
      this.crossAxisMinSize = 0.0,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  Widget makeAligned(Widget widget, CrossAxisAlignment alignment) {
    switch (alignment) {
      case CrossAxisAlignment.center:
        return Center(
          child: widget,
        );
      case CrossAxisAlignment.start:
        return Align(
          alignment: _startAlignment(),
          child: widget,
        );
      case CrossAxisAlignment.end:
        return Align(
          alignment: _endAlignment(),
          child: widget,
        );
      case CrossAxisAlignment.stretch:
        return widget;
      default:
        throw 'Alignment not implemented';
    }
  }

  Alignment _startAlignment() {
    if (direction == Axis.horizontal) {
      return Alignment.topCenter;
    } else {
      return Alignment.centerLeft;
    }
  }

  Alignment _endAlignment() {
    if (direction == Axis.horizontal) {
      return Alignment.bottomCenter;
    } else {
      return Alignment.centerRight;
    }
  }

  Widget _intrinsicWidget({required Widget child}) {
    if (direction == Axis.horizontal) {
      return IntrinsicHeight(child: child);
    } else {
      return IntrinsicWidth(child: child);
    }
  }

  Widget _minSizeWidget() {
    if (direction == Axis.horizontal) {
      return SizedBox(height: crossAxisMinSize);
    } else {
      return SizedBox(width: crossAxisMinSize);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(flexValues.length == children.length);
    assert(alignments.length == children.length);
    List<Widget> _children = children.asMap().entries.map((MapEntry entry) {
      Widget w = entry.value;
      int index = entry.key;
      int? flexValue = flexValues[index];
      CrossAxisAlignment caa = alignments[index];
      Widget _aligned = makeAligned(w, caa);
      return flexValue == null
          ? _aligned
          : Flexible(flex: flexValue, child: _aligned);
    }).toList();
    return _intrinsicWidget(
      child: Flex(
        direction: direction,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [_minSizeWidget(), ..._children],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VariableCrossAxisAlignmentRow extends VariableCrossAxisAlignmentFlex {
  VariableCrossAxisAlignmentRow(
      {required List<int?> flexValues,
      required List<CrossAxisAlignment> alignments,
      required List<Widget> children,
      double minHeight = 0.0,
      Key? key})
      : super(
            alignments: alignments,
            children: children,
            flexValues: flexValues,
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            crossAxisMinSize: minHeight);
}

class VariableCrossAxisAlignmentColumn extends VariableCrossAxisAlignmentFlex {
  VariableCrossAxisAlignmentColumn(
      {required List<int?> flexValues,
      required List<CrossAxisAlignment> alignments,
      required List<Widget> children,
      double minWidth = 0.0,
      Key? key})
      : super(
            alignments: alignments,
            children: children,
            flexValues: flexValues,
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            crossAxisMinSize: minWidth);
}
```