# Why the text is not align center in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi All I am learning flutter and I want the text to be align-center inside the column but the property crossAlignmentCenter is not working can anyone look and told what i am doing wrong here

[image]

````
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("hello"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32,right: 32,top: 32),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("Log In", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that by default columns do not take all available space on the cross axis. So in your example, the column is only as thick as the child it holds. Therefore centering it does not change anything. If you are looking for a solution go to [Why CrossAxisAligment not Working in Flex,Row and Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073674/why-crossaxisaligment-not-working-in-flex-row-and-column)

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the `Column` widget with a `SizedBox` or a `Container` with the `width` of `double.infinity`. This allows `Column` to extend as much as the parent allows.

Replace `Padding` widget with this,

```dart
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32, right: 32, top: 32), 
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Log In",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to make it the vertical center of the `column` add `mainAxisAlignment`  for your `column` widget.

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

If want to have it horizontal center replace your `column` widget to `row` and make sure to set `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignnment` to `center`

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your Text widget inside an Align widget to do this. this is your fixed code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("hello"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32,right: 32,top: 32),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
              Container(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child:Text("Log In", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),)
                ) ,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    );
  }
}
```